# The HTML content within PHP are not appearing only on some pages — Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, php, phtml

I am using Magento 2, I have added a piece of HTML wrapped in PHP to this page:

> CustomTemplate/Magento_Customer/templates/account/Customer.phtml

### This is the code:

```
        <div class="Container">
            <?php
                <div class="Child">some text</div>
            ?>  
        </div>
```

This works on most pages, such as the account page, and the code creates the `div.Container` and the `div.Child`. 
However, on some other pages, such as the Main page, the content wrapped in PHP are not showing. The `div.Container` is there, but the `div.Child` does not show up.

Note that this issue happens only on the Main page and some other pages, could there be any specific reason that this code works on some pages but not on the others?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use echo?

```
    <div class="Container">
        <?php
            echo '<div class="Child">some text</div>';
        ?>  
    </div>
```

Comment: I have tried, but it does not make any difference.